# Using SqlParameter in calculation

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server

I'm currently working on an SQL Application and am trying to build a query with SqlCommand and SqlParameters.
My current code looks something like this:

```
SqlCommand command = database.connection.CreateCommand();

commandTexts = "select id, @current, @comparable, name from items oder by (@current - @comparable) desc"

        SqlParameter currentParam = new SqlParameter("@current", System.Data.SqlDbType.VarChar, 9);
        currentParam.Value = "price" + current;
        SqlParameter comparableParam = new SqlParameter("@comparable", System.Data.SqlDbType.VarChar, 9);
        comparableParam.Value = "price" + comparable;
```

The value of *current* and *comparable* are calculated at runtime, they are sort of a timestamp (each is max 4 characters long). The data types in my SQl database (using SQL Server 2017 btw) is DECIMAL(10,5).
Whenever I execute the query, I get an error saying something like "types varchar and varchar are incompatible in subtract operator" and I'm just assuming that that is because the query takes the Parameter value literally instead of using it as a column name as intended. The columns are for example called "price20_5", "20_5" being the result of current and the price is added in front of it.

Now I have thought about a possible workaround with another table in the middle and loops (therefore multiple requests), or just using multiple subselects but since I intend to work with a lot of data, that seems really inefficient and possibly unnecessary.

My question is, what the best way would be to get the calculation up and running in the cleanest and most efficient way. Haven't worked a lot with SQL yet, so I'm always looking for cool new tricks to improve ;)

Thanks in advance!

Comment: There is no  SQL Server **2018** - we have 2012, 2014, 2016, 2017 and 2019 - take your pick. Running `SELECT @@VERSION` will tell you what version you really have....

Comment: `instead of using it as a table name as intended`.. What do you mean by this? What are actual sample values of `current` and `comparable` (the variables not the parameters) and why are you using varchar if the types are as you say decimal?

Comment: Assuming current and price variables are decimals, you could instead actually add them as... decimal(!) parameters and omit prepending "price" to their value in c#. Then your query can be something *like* `Select 'price'+Cast(@current as varchar) from items order by @current-@comparable`

Comment: @marc_s yea sorry, I'm using 2017. Had a typo

Comment: @pinkfloydx33 I've edited the question. The tablenames are something like "price20_5" or "price39_0". Therefore *current* and *comparable* are strings representing the numbercombination. The values stored inside the table are just regular decimals, like 10.253 f.e., and as far as I know those are subtractable.

Comment: You're saying `table names`, but do you mean `column names`? Sounds like you want to write a dynamic query with your column names instead of providing them as literal values via SqlParameters.

Comment: Begs the question why you are storing data in the column names?

Comment: @Charlieface as I've explained: the column name works as a sort of timestamp. Of course I'm going to save different data in the column itself, the number after *price* is only to reference the column I need. I'm deciding at runtime (depending on the set parameters) which column to read, therefore I need to set the column name dynamically. But luckily I already have my answer ;)

Comment: No, you are still storing some of the data in column names. Unpivot the data and store it `id, timestamp, price` or something like that. Then you don't need dynamic SQL to select it. Dynamic SQL is horrible and prone to syntax errors and injection attacks

Comment: @Charlieface I see what you mean, then I would still have to set a parameter but it would work, true. It's some good input to consider on future projects.

Comment: At a push, with just a few columns you could use a `CASE` expression. Barring that, you can still unpivot inside your current query and use that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot parameterize column names (or objects, or schemas). To do what you want you'll need to concatenate the names into the SQL string itself, taking care not to allow for SQL injection vulnerabilities. If the column name parts are all generated from your code (not user input), that's usually a good start. If the values don't need additional checks, then perhaps just:

```cs
commandTexts = $"select id, price{current}, price{comparable}, name from items oder by (price{current} - price{comparable}) desc";
```

Comment: Thanks so much, I've never thought about that! It worked!

Answer (score 0):

Try casting the two params in the order by?

```
SELECT 
id, 
@current, 
@comparable, 
name 
FROM items 
ORDER BY (CAST(@current AS DECIMAL(10,5)) - CAST(@comparable AS DECIMAL(10,5))) DESC
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe I'm missing something as there are a lot of suggestions but there are potential several problems with how you're doing things. The first, which addresses the error taking it literally, you can't subtract "price2.35" from "price3.23". You can see why?

First thing to do is use the correct data type for your params and remove the "price" string from the assignment statement...

```
SqlParameter currentParam = new SqlParameter("@current", System.Data.SqlDbType.VarChar, 9);
    currentParam.Value = "price" + current;
```

becomes

```
SqlParameter currentParam = new SqlParameter("@current", System.Data.SqlDbType.Int, 9);
    currentParam.Value = current;
```

Comment: The *price32_5* is the column name, I want to subtract the values inside the column, which in normal SQL (or at least MySQL which I've worked with in the past) can be achieved by writing something like "columnName - columnName2" which will then take the values in the columns and subtract them.